# How to enable users to export events into their external calendars from my web application?

Tags: import, calendar

I have written a calendar application that allows users to create events. I already expose the metadata as json-ld for the sake of webcrawlers but I would also like to make it easy for users to export events into their own calendar applications, for example, iCal or Google Calendar.

My preference would be if the option to export the event was immediately accessible from the web interface. I like that the [hEvent format](http://microformats.org/wiki/h-event) is just based on marked-up HTML, but I can't find any information on its value for end users.

The [iCalendar format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) seems to be more widely supported, but I can't see how I should make it available for users, should I give them a link to an `.ics` file that they can then import into their calendars?

Google Calendar supports manually importing ics files and will also read them automatically from emails, would it be better therefore to allow users to email themselves an `ics` file? How would this work for iCal users?